# AngularJs input[type=date] is not giving date in yyyy-mm-dd format. it gives like 2015-06-02T18:30:00.000Z

Tags: angularjs

I have used following code for input type=" date". But it gives in 2015-06-02T18:30:00.000Z format I need only 2015-06-02 format.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="newTest.startAvailability" placeholder="Start Date" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's technically giving you a variable in JavaScript date type, then calling .toISOString() on it. Wherever you're displaying your date, you need to use a date display filter like this:

```
{{newTest.startAvailability  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

**Update based on clarification in comments**
Wherever in code you're you need to have a string variable in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, just do this:

```
var yyyymmdd = newTest.startAvailability.getFullYear()+'-'+newTest.startAvailability.getMonth()+1+'-'+newTest.startAvailability.getDate();
```

now yyyymmdd has the value in the format you want.

Comment: I used this but this is not working. the date picker is also not working with this change. I want to send this Date in JSON form to database in yyyy-mm-dd formet

Comment: did you make the change inside <input ng-model="">? If so, try it without the braces. The point I'm trying to make is "use a display filter, specifically 'date'".

Comment: I dont want to display the date. I want to send that date with ajax to the server...

Comment: my 2 cents of contributing: You can call a transformer or filter directly from javascript. But ng-model doesn't allow to use transformers or filters.